# jQuery .is(':visible') not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
if($('#tab-1').is(':visible'))
    $('#extras').show();
else
    $('#extras').hide();

            <div class='col-lg-12 pull-left'>
                <div class='tab-content'>
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#tab-1" data-toggle='pill'>Lobby</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab-2" data-toggle='pill'>Television Talk</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <br />

                    <div id='tab-1' class='tab-pane active'>
                        <div class='col-lg-12'>
                            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                                <div class='panel-heading'><button class='btn btn-default'>Lobby</button> - <button class='btn btn-default'>Follow Chat</button> - <button class='btn btn-default'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span>&nbsp; 236</button> - <button class='btn btn-default'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span> &nbsp; Private</button></div>
                                <div class='panel-body'>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id='tab-2' class='tab-pane'>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

I have a tabbed div and when the id tab-1 isn't visible I don't want the div extras to show.

If the main tab (tab-1) is visible or the content is shown, I want the extras div to be shown.

If any other tab content is being shown, I want extras to be hidden.

Shouldn't the code above work?  Why wouldn't it?

Thanks.

Oh, and i'm using bootstrap's JavaScript (and css).

Comment: where is this code placed

Comment: Your syntax looks right. Is this code throwing an error in debugger?

Comment: In a separate JS file that is included at the bottom of the page and the file is surrounded with $(function() { });

Comment: I'm open to alternative solutions too.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(function( $ ){ // DOM ready (shorthand)

     $('#extras').toggle( $('#tab-1').is(':visible') );

});
```

You need to use `document.ready` handler function, to make sure your Document Object Model is read and ready to be maninpulated. Put inside your actions and functions

<sub>From the **DOCS**: http://api.jquery.com/ready/</sub>

Comment: why not `$('#extras').toggle($('#tab-1').is(':visible'))`

Comment: I have it inside of ($function() { });

Comment: @JohnSmith Can you setup a basic http://jsbin.com with your issue? Exactly when are you calling that hide/show stuff? on an specific event? Or on page load?

Comment: @JohnSmith do you have your jQuery inside a `$(document).ready(` function and inside `<script>` tags? And where is your `#extras` element?